# Why won't my git status icons change when remote modifications exist?

Tags: git, svn, tortoisegit, bonobo

I recently set up some git repositories using a Bonobo git server.  I use tortoise git and Git Source Control Provider extension for Visual Studio 2013. Whenever anyone commits and pushes code to the repository, no one else can view the changes until they do a fetch/pull.  Before I was using svn and the status icons on all of my files and folders would tell me if my code was out of date by displaying a red cross on the icon.

So I am wondering if it is an issue with my repository or my git client.

I am running git version 1.9.4 on Windows 7 and Bonobo Git Server (3.4.2.0)

Comment: git works completely different to svn. You need to pull the changes from others. The idea is a distributed placement of repositories. svn has a central one.

Comment: That's not how tortoisesvn does it, either. Tortoisesvn only updates the icon for *local* modifications.

Comment: @Ben, I'm not sure what the config is, but changes to files on our company SVN instances cause changes in the TortoiseSVN icons displayed in Windows Explorer on our local machines, provided we run **Check for modifications** from the right-click context menu on that folder.  I note that the **Check for modifications** UI includes an option, **Show items in externals**.  However, with TortoiseGit, for the life of me, I can't get **Check for modifications** to show me what has changed in remote repos, as compared to the local directory.

Comment: "Show items in externals" has nothing at all to do with the status of files on the server. "Check for modifications" does not contact the server *at all* unless you click the "Check repository" button manually. That dialog is mainly for finding *local* changes. The [list of overlays used by TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html) do *not* include any sort of "file is out of date" icon, and the "red cross" overlay is for locally deleted files, it has nothing to do with server status. That icon must have come from some other shell extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something your client could fix by internally checking with the upstream repository's branch heads (which you can do yourself with [`git ls-remote -h origin`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html)), apparently whatever you were using with svn was incessantly pinging the server for status that way.

But if there's changes, you're going to fetch them, so what's wrong with fetching when you want an uptodate status?  Fetch doesn't touch the worktree, you don't have to merge right then.  Maybe there's a config option for this in Tortoise?